# Selecting children without a certain index (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, children

I want to select some children without a certain index like using eq() in reverse.

I also need to be able to pass the index number as a variable .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$("#foo").children().not(":eq(2)");
```

This selects all children of `foo` except the 3rd one (`eq()` uses Javascript's 0-based indexing).

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/wEGrp/).

To pass a variable to it:

```
var num = "2";
$("#foo").children().not(":eq(" + num + ")").css("background-color", "red");
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/wEGrp/3/)

Comment: Thanks , How would I pass it a variable ?

Comment: What do you mean? The number in the `eq()` will be a variable?